# Titanium App Development: Recieving geo location from a smartphone

Tags: geolocation, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile app which basically will help you track the location of your friends and family based on the geolocation information from them. So I understand that this will involve getting their permission, before accessing the data.

I have a basic understanding of developing apps in Titnaium Appcelerator. But I need help in figuring out how to communicate with a third party device, ask for permission and retrieve its geolocation.

The app I am developing will be very similar to this: http://goo.gl/dvCgP

Comment: i think no permission is needed. location information is permitted while we use titanium. if you are getting some error, you may add permissions manually to tiapp.xml like ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this is by setting up a central web service, the phones themselves cannot gather GPS locations from each other, regardless of that, you cant store all the other phones information on your own device anyway.

Setup a web service that will save GPS locations when a phone posts them, then have that service return the other phones that they are connected too. Once you have that service set up, using it in Titanium is trivial:

```
// First lets get our position
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {

    if (e.error) {
        alert('Cannot get your current location');
        return;
    }

    var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
    var latitude = e.coords.latitude;

    // We need to send an object to the web service verifying who we are and holding our GPS location, construct that here
    var senObj = {userid : 'my_user_id', latitude : latitude, longitude : longitude};
    // Now construct the client, and send the object to update where we are on the web server
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            // Parse the response text from the webservice
            // This response should have the information of the other users youre connected too
            var rsp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // do something with the response from the server
            var user = rsp.otherUsers[0];
            alert('Tracking other user named '+user.userid+' at coordinates ('+user.longitude+','+user.latitude+')');
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('[ERROR] communicating with webservice.');
        }
    });

});
```